# What is the third argument for in Django url patterns?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am trying to understand it. If I write a url pattern like this

```
url(r'^$', 'newsletter.views.home', name='home'),
```

it works. and If I write it like this

```
url(r'^$', 'newsletter.views.home'),
```

it still works, but I get the following data from the server

RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got newsletter.views.contact). Pass the callable instead.
  url(r'^contact/$', 'newsletter.views.contact'),

My first question is what does the third argument do. the

```
name='home' or name='contact'. What is it reffering to.
```

and my second question is what does

```
Pass the callable instead.
```

mean? Again, I have read the docs and came here for a bit more clarity in laymen's terms. All help and advice is welcome

Comment: Note that `kwargs` is the third argument for [url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url). Since it is optional, you can leave it out, and include `name` as a keyword argument e.g. `name='home'`.

Comment: You should get the same deprecation warning whether or not you use `name` in your url patterns.

Answer (score 4):

When it says pass the callable, it means you should import the view itself and include that in your url pattern.

```
from newsletter.views import home

url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
```

Another option is to import the `views` module itself

```
# renaming allows us to import more than one views at once
from newsletter import views as newsletter_views

url(r'^$', newsletter_views.home, name='home'),
```

Naming url patterns allows you to reverse url patterns (e.g. go from a name to a url). This means you don't have to hardcode urls in your views and templates.

If you have

```
url(r'^home/$', home, name='home'),
```

then you can use `reverse('home')` in your code, and `{% url 'home' %}` in your templates, instead of writing `/home/` repeatedly.

Comment: thanks for the response. So to be clear, the third argument is no longer needed in the example you provided, right? The name='home' part or name ='contact' are no longer needed because I am importing the views.

Comment: It's **always** good practice to name your urls. The deprecation warning isn't related to whether you name your urls or not. However, it used to be possible to use the string `'newsletter_views.home'` in the url tag i.e. `{% url 'newsletter.views.home' %}`. For Django 1.10+, this will no longer work, and you **must** name your url patterns to be able to reverse them.

Comment: @alsdair I just tried what you advised from newsletter import views as newsletter_views and newsletter and views are both throwing errors

Comment: They're highlighted in red. they both have red squiggly lines under them

Comment: I can't see any problems with the imports I've written above. 'Red squiggly lines' sounds like your editor isn't properly configured. I'm afraid I can't help with that.